# Kalman Filter by Orthogonal Projection

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I'm working through the derivation for the Kalman filter using orthogonal projections. It's pretty intuitive that if we want to generate the best linear estimate for an $n$-vector $x$ using some $m$-vectors $y_0, \dots, y_t$, we would take the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto the subspace $\mathbb{R}^m$ spanned by the vectors $y_i$.

In the Kalman filter case, it seems that we assume $n>m>t$. That is, a lower dimensional observations $(y)$ than states $(x)$ we are trying to estimate. Similarly, we are trying to build a recursive estimator that uses additional observations $y_i$ such that at timestep $t$ we have $t$ observation vectors and our subspace is of dimension $t$.

My question is this: what happens when $t=m=n$? This would mean, I think, that the orthogonal projection is meaningless and it wouldn't help your filter to gain new estimates... is this correct?

Comment: $t$ is the time step here, so you should technically write it as $t_k$ where $k = 1,...,N$. The time step is irrelevant to the Kalman filter, it is just a means of dynamics propagation. What is important is the dimensionality of the state and measurements. If $m = n$ then you have as many measurements as state variables so the mapping is from $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$, which is perfectly valid. Only in the case where $m < n$ can you run into problems with observability, where the filter can’t estimate your state because of your measurement model.